# Remove a div if after it's slid out of view?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently using the following:

```
var $alertdiv = $('<div id = "alertmsg"></div>');
$alertdiv.text("Profile Image Updated");
$alertdiv.bind('click', function() {
    $(this).slideUp(200);
    });
    $("#alertmsg").slideDown("slow"); 
    setTimeout(function() { $alertdiv.slideUp(200) }, 3000);
}
```

but if the profile is updated again i've noticed that the code is adding a new alertmsg div every time and the first one is set as display:block so it's always visible. Is it possible to either remove the div from code (have tried:

```
var elem = document.getElementById("#alertmsg");
elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
```

to no avail) or to just run an if/else statement whereby the div isn't created again if it already exists? I have tried this, but again, no joy (i'm not great with JS).

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post your HTML? I’m having a hard time following you without it.

Comment: There is no HTML, the function is fired when the a form is returned.

Comment: How is there no HTML? Your code makes explicit reference to two DOM nodes.

Comment: When a form is returned successfully by ajax this happens:

`var $alertdiv = $('<div id = "alertmsg"></div>');
$alertdiv.text("Profile Image Updated");
$alertdiv.bind('click', function() {
    $(this).slideUp(200);
    });
    $("#alertmsg").slideDown("slow"); 
    setTimeout(function() { $alertdiv.slideUp(200) }, 3000);
}`

which creates the div and then slides it away. The div is coded in to the page dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to remove the div after you've executed slideUp.

```
setTimeout(function() { $alertdiv.slideUp(200, function() { $alertdiv.remove(); }) }, 3000);
```

Answer (score 1):

An if statement to see if it already exists would be

```
if($('#alertmsg') === undefined)
```

and **Matthijs Bierman** already has this, but to remove it, you would just `$('#alertmsg').remove()`

To put it all together, you would have

```
if($('#alertmsg') === undefined)
    var $alertdiv = $('<div id = "alertmsg"></div>');
    $alertdiv.text("Profile Image Updated");
    $alertdiv.bind('click', function() {
        $(this).slideUp(200);
        });
        $("#alertmsg").slideDown("slow"); 
        setTimeout(function() { $alertdiv.slideUp(200) }, 3000);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var div = $('<div />', {
        id   : 'alertmsg',
        text : 'Profile Image Updated',
        on   : {
            click : function() {
                $(this).stop().slideUp(200, function() {
                    $(this).remove();
                });
            }
        }
}).appendTo('body').end()
  .slideDown('slow').delay(3000).slideUp(200, function() {
    $(this).remove();
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/47fBV/)